# Creating a generic update/install script from a Sql Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-project

Can you create a generalized *deployment script* from a Sql Server Db Project in VS 2015 that doesn't require a schema compare / publish against a specific target database?

Some background:

We are using `Sql Server Database projects` to manage our database schema. Primarily we are using the projects to generate dacpacs that get pushed out to our development environments. They also get used for brand new installations of our product. Recently we have developed an add-on to our product and have created a new db project for it, referencing our core project. For new installations of our product where clients want the add-on, our new project will be deployed.

The problem we are having is that we need to be able to generate a "generic" upgrade script. Most of our existing installations were not generated via these projects and all contain many "custom" stored procedures/etc specific to that client's installation. I am looking for a way to generate a script that would do an "If Not Exists/Create + Alter" without needing to specify the target database.

Our add-on project only contains stored procedures and a couple tables, all of which will be new to any client opting for this add-on. I need to avoid dropping items not in the project while being able to deploy all of our new "stuff". I've found the option to `Include Composite Objects` which I can uncheck so that the deployment is specific to our add-on, but publishing still requires me to specify a target database so that a schema compare can be performed and I get scripts that are specific to that particular database. I've played with pretty much every option and cannot find a solution.

**Bottom Line:** Is there a way for me to generate a generic script that I can give to my deployment team whenever the add-on is requested on an existing install without needing to do a schema compare or publish for each database directly from the project?

Right now I am maintaining a separate set of .sql files in our (non db) project following the `if not exists/create+alter` paradigm that match the items in the db project. These get concatenated during build of our add on so that we can give our deployment team a script to run. This is proving to be cumbersome and we'd like to be able to make use of the database projects for this, if at all possible.

Comment: Could you put your "add-on" objects in a separate project, with a reference to your main project?  Maintain a "clean" DB and generate the "add-on" script against that clean DB. It should generate just the Create statements. If you need Alters, you may be better off having the deploy team run SQLPackage to generate the scripts. You could create a batch file to do that pretty easily. Just give them the updated dacpacs and the process is the same - gen script, review if necessary, run.

Comment: It's already in a separate project with a reference like you suggest. This approach could work but if we ever need to update one of the stored procedures (bug fix for example) this approach wouldn't work which is why I'm looking for alters.  I'm not familiar with SqlPackage I'll have to take a look into it.

Comment: Basically, you give the dacpacs to your installers. They run SQLPackage (maybe through a batch file or PowerShell) to point it at the server/DB to update. It would then generate the script or update directly.  Sounds like they already have access to the servers so should be able to do this. SQLPackage should also be included on the servers or it can be run locally for the installer as long as they can see the target DB. This might help: https://schottsql.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/ssdt-publishing-your-project/

Comment: So they'd get the 'full' dacpac but using a publish profile that only does what I want (no composites, drop/ignore settings) with the targeted db would deploy just the portions I need?  At least that's how I read your article. If this is the case please post this an answer. I came up with a hacky work around that involves a secondary build configuration that includes a custom predeploy script (only in that configuration) that drops all my procedures etc and backs up and restores (via another custom post deploy) but it involves me maintaining all the drops in that script. Not the best but works

Comment: Done. Do watch out for customers who get "creative" in the changes they make to your database. Most customers aren't too bad, but some can make a whole bunch of changes that interfere with the app itself. For those customers you might need to enforce a "drop objects not found". Most times, I'd avoid doing that as customers sometimes create helper procs/tables outside of your schema. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is to give the dacpacs to your installers. They run SQLPackage (maybe through a batch file or PowerShell) to point it at the server/DB to update. It would then generate the script or update directly. Sounds like they already have access to the servers so should be able to do this. SQLPackage should also be included on the servers or it can be run locally for the installer as long as they can see the target DB. This might help: schottsql.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/ssdt-publishing-your-project

There are a couple of examples of using PowerShell to do this, but it depends on how much you need to control DB names or Server names. A simple batch file where you edit/replace the Server/DB Names might suffice. I definitely recommend a publish profile and if this is hitting customer databases they could have modified, setting the "do not drop if not in project" options that show up is almost essential. As long as your customers haven't made wholesale changes to core objects, you should be good to go.